# Play 2 separate sound files (wav) on a single button press, one after the other

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to be able to play 2 separate sound files (wav) on a single button press, one after the other. The code I use for playing one is:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Applause" ofType:@"wav"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        theAudio.delegate = self;
        [theAudio play];
```

Have you any idea how this can be modified to play 2 sound or would I need to create another action.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [delegate method](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioPlayerDelegate) to start the next sound:

```
 - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag



    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio1=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath1] error:NULL];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio2=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath2] error:NULL];
    theAudio1.delegate = self;
    [theAudio1 play];

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag  {
    [theAudio2 play];    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am new to this so forgive my ignorance, would I include these methods in the .h file i.e. - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying; and implement as your code suggests in .m file?

Comment: No, you not need to declare delegate method in .h